# How to publish apps to Apple app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am a beginner in developing iOS apps. I am currently building one simple app for personal organization use and I want to publish the app. But all tutorials did not lead me to be able to publish the apps.

For example, image number did not show the "View details" (as the most tutorial showing that "view details".
And for image number 2, after I log into app developer account, I cannot see the certificate, etc. option (as most tutorial shown).

I just build the app using simulator since I don't have iPhone/iPad device. I got error

> failed to create provisioning profile.

Is that possible to publish the apps without running it on the real device first?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you paid the fee and "signed" the relevant contracts through iTunesConnect?

Comment: Start with what @PaulW11 is asking. Then, set things up in iTunesConnect. Finally, try using Xcode's Archive and Upload feature. For specific details, this two part tutorial (just over a year old but well worth following) did the trick for me: https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1?utm_source=raywenderlich.com+Weekly&utm_campaign=2ddc63ecca-raywenderlich_com_Weekly6_28_2016&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_83b6edc87f-2ddc63ecca-415124905 https://www.raywenderlich.com/127939/submit-an-app-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Have you created and downloaded a provisioning profile on your developer account? Have you created a cert that allows you to do that ^ ? Have you registered your device on itunes connect so you can build on device? These are all things you have to do. After you do these things, you have to select Product > Archive for Generic iOS Devices. After it's done archiving, you can upload to the iTunes Store. Make sure your version number matches the app that you create on iTunesConnect. Build Numbers must also increase or the app store will reject your build.